# StartStoryboard on another control

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have this xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StoryboardTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 0.5"/>
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="rt" Angle="0"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Start">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Storyboard.TargetName="pbar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Duration="0:0:6"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="1" x:Name="btn1">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bs1">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" x:Name="btn2">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bs2">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="3" x:Name="btn3">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bs3">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="pbar" Maximum="100" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see there are 4 buttons(Start button - the main one, buttons 1, 2 and 3) and a progress bar. When I click buttons 1,2 or 3 they rotate slightly. My question is how can I trigger that rotations(which are described by respective storyboards) in Start's button EventTrigger? Is it possible to achieve this not writing 3 other storyboards in the Start button but invoking already attached storyboards for buttons 1,2,3 in xaml only?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardName">
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" Storyboard.TargetName="btn1" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" Storyboard.TargetName="btn2" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" Storyboard.TargetName="btn3" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

 <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Start">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardName}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

Doubleanimations declared in storyboard will run simultaneously.

```
 <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=start, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                ...
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Is there any way to trigger already attached storyboard? In my real case there are number of buttons with declared storyboards, it's quite tedious task to put them all into resources and reassign.

Comment: You can use DataTrigger to determine if start button is pressed and if so then run attached storyboard. Take a look at updated answear.